# trying to get darksky api data in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I connected to a third party api and trying to get the data looping through the object but I keep getting errors like the data is not there

Please see my controller and view below

Controller

```
function weather() {

    $client = new Client();
    $req = $client->get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/6c314524bbb5e8ea74d27ea433a64a19/37.8267,-122.4233');
    $response = $req->getBody()->getContents();
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    return view('weather', compact('data'));
}
```

Blade View

```
 @foreach($data as $r)
      <span>{{ $r->latitude }}</span>
 @endforeach
```

And this is the error

**Trying to get property 'latitude' of non-object**

What am I doing wrong please?

I mean the data is there, see pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z3RA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data` is an array, access the `latitude` as a key in your view

```html
<span>{{ $data['latitude'] }}</span>
```

Hope this helps